# Do the torch.fft module functions work on multiple GPUs?

Tags: pytorch, fft, distributed-computing, multi-gpu

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the PyTorch FFT functions on a single tensor that is distributed over multiple GPUs. I don't have any experience with multi-GPU computing (and I don't have multiple devices to test this with), but I believe this has more to do with model parallel rather than [other questions](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-fft-on-multiple-gpus/43532) asking about `DataParallel` with FFTs. The kinds of operations I'm interested in seem to be [possible in CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#multiple-GPU), but I haven't found any resources indicating that PyTorch exposes the same functionality.

If it is possible to do this, what would the code look like?